# How to load data to Silverlight? Json or WCF Service?

Tags: silverlight, json, wcf

This question came to my head while working with a map in silverlight that displays some harbours, and after mouse_overing the harbour, its data gets displayed in the screen. I did it and now it works, using WCF service, but I get some big delays. My friend told me that maybe Json could handle better with this delay, but I have no idea.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing WCF with binary encoding (custom binding) instead of XML (basichttpbinding)? That could save a lot of time.

http://www.mostlydevelopers.com/blog/post/2009/10/14/Silverlight-3-WCF-Binary-Message-Encoding.aspx

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/04/05/silverlight-3-experimenting-with-wcf-s-binary-xml-encoder.aspx

Otherwise, json could be faster but I think the conversion must be done in last option. You certainly can (must) optimize either Server or Client code. For example : Are you returning only the needed Data or a whole object fully populated with list of childs you don't care?

Comment: I'm returning just the objects I need, using basichttpbinding, and just useful data.

Comment: Ok so you can try binary binding. It typically speeds up by 30% your communications. I looked for a JSon vs SOAP in wcf performance comparison and I think it really depends on your data. I would still go with WCF and binaries (more straightforward and easier to serialize) because your bandwith is not so important. If you did mobile developement I would recommend json though.